# Magento 2 : URL issue with index.php

Tags: magento2

i have tried with `site.local/index.php/admin_1l9rnp` but automatically redirect to remove slash after url `(site.localindex.php/admin_1l9rnp)` please suggest how to solve this problem.

this is issue :
[image]

i want this : [image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have put correct url in database as base_url

If yes then remove var/cache and generated/ and pub/static/ folder and recompile and deploy again.

Hope this will help from my side.

Please replace this htaccess file content on root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: I have already used these steps, but not work

Comment: I have updated my answer, could you please update htaccess content on root...

Comment: ok, let me check

Comment: dear navneet my issue has been solved but not helpfull .htaccess. i have check again DB & add url /
and 
thanks for reply